# WinUSB installation ERROR: Exit code : 512

Tags: grub2, partitioning, windows, bios, devices

Tried installing Windows 10 on SD card (Tried using 2 ubuntu PCs and both have same error. I have made previous bootable sd cards successfully on those PCs), all files extracted to the SD card, however I get a grub error:

```
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
```

I would appreciate any help in this subject (error details below). Thanks in advance.

```
Installation failed !
Exit code: 512
Log:
Formating device...
Mounting...
mount: block device /home/radek/Desktop/Microsoft Windows 10 6IN1 AIO ENGLISH 2015/Win10AIOx86x64EN-US_2015.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
Copying...
Installing grub...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
Error occured !
Syncing...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78:  9963 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 12306 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1445017506_4786'...
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1445017506_4786'...
```

Comment: You can create a partition using gparted.